# How to get value from one of several possible URL parameters?

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, url-parameters

I want to retrieve values form url parameters, but the parameters are not constant: it can be "**referer=**" or "**utm_source=**" or "**source=**".

I can get the value with

```
url.searchParams.get("referer");
```

Complete script for now :

```
function() {
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var ref = url.searchParams.get("referer");

if (ref == undefined) {
 return "No Referer";
} else {
  return ref; 
}
}
```

Can I include some regex like:

```
var ref = url.searchParams.get.match(/referer|source|utm\_source/g);
```

Comment: Any one of the parameter can get defiantly right?

Comment: Can iterate `url.searchParams.keys()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I include some regex

No. That isn't a feature of `get`.

You can use a set of `||`s:

```
var ref = url.searchParams.get("referer") || url.searchParams.get("source") || url.searchParams.get("utm_source");
```

Or take an array of key names, map them to the values in the URL, filter out any which don't have a value, then take the first (and presumably only) value off the array.

```
var possible_key_names = ["referer", "source", "utm_source"];
var ref = possible_key_names
    .map(name => url.searchParams.get(name))
    .filter(value => !!value)
    .shift();
```

Comment: I just tested your first solution and it seems to work out fine !

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the [`searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) like so:

```js
var url = new URL("https://example.com/page?referer=&utm_source=google");
var value;
for (var [key, val] of url.searchParams) {
  if (key.match(/^(referer|source|utm_source)$/) && val !== "") {
    value = val;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(value);
```

Comment: I got this error message : "This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: for-of loop."

Comment: @B4b4j1 you can use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/forEach) (if available) but I seem to like the `map` idea in the other answer.